# Angular.js working with a single element in a JSON Document

Tags: json, angularjs, date, formatting

I have some JSON e.g.

```
  [{
    'name': 'test',
    'phone': '012345678',
    'date': '02/03/2014'
   },
   { ... }
  ]
```

A controller something like :

```
var app = angular.module('App', []);


app.controller('NameListCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

    $http.get('/api/v1/names.json').success(function(names) {
            $scope.names = names;
    });
});
```

HTML/JADE something like :

```
div#names(ng-controller="NameListCtrl")
   li.course_list(ng-repeat="name in names | orderBy:'date1'")
    span
     {{name.date}})                    // I want to do some formatting on this
    span
     {{name.name}}
```

I would like to perform a formatting operation on each date, is there a way of doing so without using filters ? I have seen something using the `$httpProvider`.

Comment: What do u want to do with the date?  And why not use filters, this is what they are built for built in date filter... `({ date_expression | date : date : format}})`  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way to do it in the controller... insert your own `filter` func.

```
app.controller('NameListCtrl', function($scope, $http, $filter) {

    $http.get('/api/v1/names.json').success(function(names) {
          angular.forEach(names, function(item){
              item.date = $filter('date')(item.date, "shortDate");
          });
          $scope.names = names;
    }); 
 });
```

You could also use jade and do:

```
{{name.date|date:'shortDate'}})
```

Comment: It seems that if I do this, my format is now correct but `orderBy` no longer works ...

Comment: If you change the date to some human string you will have issues.  Because you are doing string sorting... I would recommend using a sep field `item.dateFormated = formatfunc(item.date).`  OR* use the second example where you just format it in the template when you use it.

Comment: Yes that works, I added `item.orig = item.date` and sorted on `orig`